# MySQL counting same strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example of MySQL columns data:

```
stringone
stringthree
stringtwo
stringone
stringone
stringthree
```

How can I get the following result from MySQL with PHP or mysql_ itself? I don't know strings content.

```
stringone    3x
stringthree  2x
stringtwo    1x
```

Thank you for your suggestions and direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT columnname1,count(columnname1) 
  FROM tablename 
   GROUP BY conlumnname1;
```

## http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecc99/1

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT string, COUNT(1) FROM table GROUP BY string
```

Comment: @user3424754 : Is that what are you looking for ?

Comment: Insted of SUM() you need to use COUNT()

Answer (score 1):

#### This is an alternate PHP - based solution

You can use `array_count_values()` for that.

After you get the result data in an array , do this..

Say if `$resultfromSQL = array('stringone','stringthree','stringtwo','stringone','stringone','stringthree');` holds data from the `SELECT` query..

```
$resultfromSQL = array_count_values($resultfromSQL);
//Since you need the **x** multiplier , you can do an `array_walk()`
array_walk($resultfromSQL,function (&$v){ $v=$v.'x';});
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [stringone] => 3x
    [stringthree] => 2x
    [stringtwo] => 1x
)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/138562)</kbd>

Comment: @user3424754, Its ok mate :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said use `group by` and a count.  You can also order by the count field i you want (I notice yours are in descending order by occurance):

```
select string_col, count(1) as num
from table
group by string_col
order by num desc
```